# No matching function exception when passing vector as a parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-errors

I got a weird compile error in the following code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int function(vector<int>& nums) {
        //Did something
        int len = nums.size();
        int mid = len / 2;
        if (nums[mid] < nums[0]) {
            vector<int> newVec(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + mid);
            return function(newVec);
        }
        else 
            return function(vector<int>(nums.begin() + mid + 1, nums.end()));
    }
};
```

The error occured in:
`return function(vector<int>(nums.begin() + mid + 1, nums.end()));`

It seems to me that it works perfectly fine if I construct the vector first, then pass it to the function. Like what I did in the block under `if`:

```
vector<int> newVec(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + mid);
return function(newVec);
```

But if I combine these two steps, the error occurs. Could anyone please explain that for me? Many thanks~

=========================================================================

Edit:

The compile error was

`no matching function for call to ‘Solution::function(std::vector<int>)’`

Comment: Please post the "weird compiler error" message.

Comment: Just a quick question. It might be because it's 4 AM, but I kinda see an infinite recursion here. Is that weird compiler error a stack overflow?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: `vector<int>& nums` is an *lvalue reference*. You must pass an lvalue.  To allow both of these uses, change to `vector<int> const &nums` , which you should be doing anyway.

Comment: Consider redesigning `function` to accept an iterator range in the first place. Then you can run your whole algorithm just looking at a single buffer, instead of making heaps of copies of parts of it.

Comment: @M.M Thanks. It works!

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int>& nums` is an *lvalue reference*. You must pass an lvalue.  To allow both of these uses, change to `vector<int> const &nums` , which you should be doing anyway.
Consider redesigning `function` to accept an iterator range in the first place. Then you can run your whole algorithm just looking at a single buffer, instead of making heaps of copies of parts of it.
                    – M.M